# Connecting localhosted drupal 7 with remote SQL Server 2000 database or Oracle 10g

Tags: sql-server, drupal, drupal-7, oracle10g

I have installed XAMPP in my local system.I have a remote system with SQL Server  installed. How can I connect to this server from Drupal that is running in my local system with XAMPP server? My operating system is Windows XP. Is it possible?

Is it possible to connect remote oracle10g database.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have Drupal up and running backed by a MySQL/MariaDB database, and now you would like to connect to a remote Oracle database through a custom module of yours. If my assumption is correct, then have a look at db_set_active() for how to switch between databases.

If you would like Drupal to be backed by an Oracle database, as opposed to a MySQL/MariaDB, then I'd say you should have a look at the [Oracle driver project](http://drupal.org/project/oracle) for Drupal. I haven't tried it myself, but it might be the best place to start.